# Write a function to check whether or not a string respects the Hexadecimal notation

Tags: r, string, split

I would like to write a function that outputs "TRUE" or "FALSE" depending on whether, or not, the input corresponds to a color's hexadecimal notation.

I am a beginner with R (and coding) and came up with a basic, not-elegant and long idea of code (that doesn't work...). In a few words, splitting up the strings vector with strslipt(vector, split="") and then checking successively within a for loop if each component is either greater than 9 or corresponds to a letter different from the first six letters of the alphabet.

```
ab <- strsplit(a, split="")
ab[[1]][1]

for(i in 2:nchar(a)) {
if(!is.character(a)) {
stop("invalid input; a string expectef")
}
if (ab[[1]][1] != '#') {
c <- 'FALSE' 
}
if (ab[[1]][1] > '10') {
c <-  'FALSE'
}
if (ab[[1]][i] != 'A') {
c <- 'FALSE' 
}
if (ab[[1]][i] != 'a') {
c <- 'FALSE'
}
if (ab[[1]][i] != 'B') {
c <- 'FALSE'  
}
if (ab[[1]][i] != 'b') {
c <- 'FALSE'
}
if (ab[[1]][i] != 'C') {
c <- 'FALSE' 
}
if (ab[[1]][i] != 'c') {
c <- 'FALSE'
}
if (ab[[1]][i] != 'D') {
c <- 'FALSE'  
}
if (ab[[1]][i] != 'd') {
  c <- 'FALSE' 
 }
if (ab[[1]][i] != 'E') {
c <- 'FALSE'
}
if (ab[[1]][i] != 'e') {
c <- 'FALSE')
}
if (ab[[1]][i] != 'F') {
c <- 'FALSE'  
}
if (ab[[1]][i] != 'f') {
c <- 'FALSE')
 }
 if(c != 'FALSE') {
  c <- 'TRUE'
  }
   return(c)
  }
```

Thanks very much for your help!!

Comment: What is your specific question? Where does your function currently go wrong, and what should it do instead? You should also gives some examples of strings that should return true or false.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex expression in `grepl`.  First a simple example to look for two digit hexadecimals, to get the idea:

```
x = c('#2A', '&33', '#e4', '#EG')
grepl('^#[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}$', x)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

How it works:

- `^` means that the pattern must be at the start of the string.  I.e., no characters before # are allowed
- `#` matches itself, so this must be the 1st character
- `[0-9A-F-a-f]` matches any character in the range 0-9, A-F or a-f
- `{2}` means we need exactly 2 such characters
- `$` means the pattern must also be at the end of the string - so no additional characters are permitted

Color strings in R must have either 6 or 8 hex digits, depending whether they include an alpha value.  So to look for these two possibilities, we can do

```
grepl('^#[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}$', x) | grepl('^#[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}$', x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
hexa <- "#FFFFFF"
output = !(is.na(strtoi(stringr::str_sub(hexa, 2), 16L)))
output
```

Comment: Nice approach. Unfortunately it fails on values that would give an integer overflow. e.g. try `hexa=c("#99887766", x="#11223344")`.  Also, should really check for the `#` too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for these feedbacks. I think that I basically come up with the beginning of a better solution, using the stringr() package. Here is my code:

```
is_hex <- function(a= 'a sentence') {
 if(!is.character(a)) {
stop("invalid input; a string was expected")
}
 if (nchar(a) != '7') {
  return(as.logical("FALSE"))
 }
 if (substr(a, 1,1 ) != '#') {
  return(as.logical("FALSE"))
  }

   if (str_detect(a, pattern='[G-Z g-z]') == 'FALSE') {

    result <- as.logical("TRUE")
   }
   else {
    result <- as.logical("FALSE")
   }

    return(result)

  }
```

Now the problem that I face is that the :

```
       if(!is.character(a)) {
       stop("invalid input; a string was expected")
        }
```

doesn't not seem to work. In fact, if I evaluate my function is_hex(a='TRUE') then I get False and not an error as expected.

Thanks very much!